# Can't use LINQ queries on elements in IWebDriver?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, selenium

I'm trying to do something something

```
IWebElement toClick = browser.FindElements(By.CssSelector("table.some-table tr")).First(elem => elem.Text == "someText");
```

but it looks like `FindElements` returns a `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>`. So am I correct that it means I have to do

```
IWebElement toClick; 
foreach(var elem in browser.FindElements(By.CssSelector("table.some-table tr")))
    if(elem.Text == "someText")
    {
       toClick = elem;
       break;
    }
```

or is there another way?

Comment: `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>` is an `IEnumerable<T>` so, assuming that you have `using System.Linq;` statement in the scope, it should work. Otherwise specify what exactly happens when you build/run that LINQ code - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist.

Comment: @EugenePodskal That's what I was forgetting! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your comparing string that may not work anyway in my experience you'd Have to use .Equals("SomeText") rather than =="Some Text"

Comment: unless you are adding case insensitivity or the like to the `.Equals` call the statements are synonymous.